# Single File Into Multiple Files

Tags: batch-file

I have a csv file with 4 columns and 279 rows that i need split into individual files.

I am currently using the following code but there is just one small problem, i need it that when it creates the new file that for each column it adds a new line. At the moment it prints off the 4 columns in one row

e.g

```
23/07/2014 11:00    24/07/2014 09:27    35386515447 1771969 s walsh
```

Needs to be

23/07/2014 11:00

24/07/2014 09:27

35386515447

1771969 s walsh

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "destdir=c:\destdir"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n "." Message.txt') DO (
 >"%destdir%\filename%%a.txt" ECHO(%%b)
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Need a clearer explanation. Do you want 4 files, one each for col1..4 or do you want 1106 files, each containing a line/column or do you want 1 file containing the logical fields of each record broken over 4 lines (with or without empty lines between) or do you want 279 files, each of the four columns split over successive lines (with or without empty lines between)? Is each line formatted identically - same number of characters per field?

Comment: Sorry if i was unclear,
I have 1 file with 4 columns and 279 lines.
I need 279 files with the info from all the four columns but under each other, so a new line between each of the column info
23/07/2014 11:00 (new line)
24/07/2014 09:27 (new line)
35386515447 (new line)
1771969 s walsh (new line)

Answer (score 0):

Test this - paste it into Notepad and where it says `TAB` replace it with a tab character.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "destdir=c:\destdir"
FOR /f "tokens=1,*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n "." Message.txt') DO (
  FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=TAB" %%b IN ("%%a") DO (
    >>"%destdir%\filename%%a.txt" ECHO(%%b
    >>"%destdir%\filename%%a.txt" ECHO(%%c
    >>"%destdir%\filename%%a.txt" ECHO(%%d
    >>"%destdir%\filename%%a.txt" ECHO(%%e
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around, i got them all into individual files seperated by commas, open all the documents in notepad ++ and did a replace of all commas with \n